# Python - Appending a column to a list of DataFrames

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a list that is comprised of DataFrames where I would like to iterate over the list of DataFrames and insert a column to each DataFrame based on an array.

Below is a small example that I have created for illustrative purposes. I would do this manually if it was only 4 DataFrames but my dataset is much larger:

```
#Create dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(range(0,10)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(range(10,20)))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(range(20,30)))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(list(range(30,40)))

#Create list of Dataframes
listed_dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4]

#Create list of dates
Dates = ['2015-05-15','2015-02-17', '2014-11-14', '2014-08-14']

#Objective: Sequentially append each instance of "Dates" to a new column in each dataframe
#First, create list of locations for iterations
locations = [0,1,2,3]

#Second, create for loop to iterate over [Need help here]
#Example: for the 1st Dataframe in the list of dataframes, add a column 'Date' that 
#         has the the 1st instance of the 'Dates' list for every row,
#         then for the 2nd DataFrame in the list of dataframes, add the 2nd instance of the 'Dates' list for every row
for i in Dates:
    for a in locations:
        listed_dfs[a]['Date'] = i

print(listed_dfs)
```

The problem with the above for loop is that it applies the last date first,  then it does not apply the 2nd date to the 2nd DataFrame, only the 1st date for each DataFrame.

**Desired Output from for loop:**

```
listed_dfs[0]['Date'] = Dates[0]
listed_dfs[1]['Date'] = Dates[1]
listed_dfs[2]['Date'] = Dates[2]
listed_dfs[3]['Date'] = Dates[3]

pd.concat(listed_dfs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your for loop to

```
for i,j in zip(Dates,locations):
        listed_dfs[j]['Date'] = i
```

Answer (score 2):

Going with your desired output:

```
listed_dfs[0]['Date'] = Dates[0]
listed_dfs[1]['Date'] = Dates[1]
listed_dfs[2]['Date'] = Dates[2]
listed_dfs[3]['Date'] = Dates[3]

pd.concat(listed_dfs)
```

Notice that the index values are the same for a row, so, 0 and 0, 1 and 1, and so on.. That's essentially what you need.

```
for i in range(len(Dates)):
    listed_dfs[i]['Date'] = Dates[i]

pd.concat(listed_dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have undestood it well, the problem is that you are overwriting the column 'Date' in all four dataframes on each iteration on Dates. A solution may be only one 'for' loop like this:

```
for a in locations:
    listed_dfs[a]['Date'] = Dates[a]
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as in your example, you loop through your dataframes sequentially, you can `zip` dataframes and dates as below.

```
for df, date in zip(listed_dfs, Dates):
    df['Date'] = date
```

This removes the need for the `locations` list.